In android studio I got error: Cannot load data from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/api/icon?pluginId=io.namaek2.plugins&theme=DARCULA (statusCode=403)
Android Studio emulator is getting terminated.
I tried all ways like wiping data, invalidate and restart.
All devices are not getting started and showing error as

The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6a_APl_30_native has terminated.

Then, I saw log in idea.log, I got error as:

Cannot load data from
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/api/icon?pluginId=io.namaek2.plugins&theme=DARCULA
(statusCode=403)


HTTP status 403 means FORBIDDEN. Which does not sound good.

just put a path of emulator in system variable, this fixed my error.
the error I was getting in idea.log is:
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
